# How to list multiple results returned from VLOOKUP using single formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, textjoin

I have a sample table to get the matches and need to list in a column. `VLOOKUP` brings only first matched column as known. So how can I list those values using only one formula?

> Here the table:

[image]

I need to get the values which first column value equals 1 and write the corresponding name next it. So how can I do this?

Comment: Here is something that you can do: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html But it really looks like quite a lot of work...

Comment: @Vityata, I prefer VBA instead :)

Comment: Anyone prefers VBA instead of nested Excel formulas :)

Comment: @Vityata nope, not me.  I would rather use formulas if I can/

Comment: @ScottCraner - take a look at the nested formula, that I refer to and consider again - there are 4 nesting levels there :)

Comment: [TEXTJOIN for xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050#50719050).

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

With Office 365 we use FILTER instead of the IF below:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(B1:B6,A1:A6=1,""))
```

---

Original Answer

If you have Office 365 Excel then use this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A1:A6=1,B1:B6,""))
```

This needs to be entered as an array by hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then attach a module to your workbook in the VBE and post this code:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

And enter the formula as described above.

---

If on the other hand you do not want it in one cell but a simple list then use this array formula in D2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$6=1)*(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$1:$B$6)=0),0)),"")
```

Again it is an array formula and needs to entered by hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copied/dragged down:

[image]

Comment: I have Office 2013, I tried this function and it didnt wor for me

Comment: @AliTor see edits, you may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: @AliTor did you try either of the other options.