# TEXTJOIN for xl2010/xl2013 with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, user-defined-functions, textjoin

I have 2 worksheets. The 1st worksheet has about 100 rows but we are only interested column Y. The cells in column Y has a mixture of blank cells (""), text and numbers, and cells that displays #N/A. Similar to the picture but with a bigger data-set.

[image: Column L]

In the 2nd worksheet, there is a cell that I would like to capture the cells with 'texts and numbers' and display it each record in a different line within the same cell (e.g. if there were 12 out of a 100 cells with 'texts and numbers', then I would like to display this information in a particular cell in the 2nd worksheet. Like this:

[image]

I have tried something like this but it seems to only capture the 1st row of text only (e.g. the title row):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('1Comms'!Y:Y,MATCH(TRUE,'1Comms'!Y:Y<>"",0)),"")
```

Is there a way to miss off the title as well?

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of xl do you have? Is the newer [tag:textjoin] function available.

Comment: @Jeeped I have excel 2013... Do you think it's possible? I've been told it's quite difficult and it's easier to texts in cells one by one?

Comment: A UDF makes it easier, a formula to check 100 rows is unrealistic and over-complicated. The [tag:textjoin] makes it easy.

Comment: @Jeeped do you have an example that I can apply it to my question? It would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I've been playing around with a TEXTJOINIFS that I might be able to easily add *ignore errors* to. I'll have a look.

Comment: @Jeeped that's great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This TextJoinIfs user-defined-function (aka UDF) provides basic [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) functionality to Excel 2003 - 2013 versions as well as expanded functionality for all versions by adding optional error control, uniqueness, sorting and a paramarray of conditions for easy criteria.

This TextJoinIfs UDF code belongs in a public module code sheet; e.g. Book1 - Module1 (code).

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TextJoinIfs(delim As String, iOptions As Long, iIgnoreHeaderRows As Long, _
                            rng As Range, ParamArray pairs()) As Variant
    'TEXTJOINIFS - Basic TEXTJOIN functionality for XL2003-XL2013 versions
    '              Expanded TEXTJOINIFS functionality for all versions
    ' =TextJoinIfs(<delimiter>, <options>, <header_rows>, <string_range>, [criteria_range1, criteria1], [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)
    '        OPTIONS
    '     +2 Include blanks
    '     +4 Include worksheet errrors
    '     +8 Unique list
    '     +16 Sort ascending (cannot be used with 17)
    '     +17 Sort descending (cannot be used with 16)

    If Not CBool(UBound(pairs) Mod 2) Then
        TextJoinIfs = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, a As Long, arr As Variant
    Dim bIncludeBlanks As Boolean, bIncludeErrors As Boolean, bUniqueList As Boolean
    Dim bSorted As Boolean, bDescending As Boolean

    bIncludeBlanks = CBool(2 And iOptions)
    bIncludeErrors = CBool(4 And iOptions)
    bUniqueList = CBool(8 And iOptions)
    bSorted = CBool(16 And iOptions)
    bDescending = CBool(1 And iOptions)

    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange.Offset(iIgnoreHeaderRows - rng.Parent.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row + 1, 0))

    With rng
        ReDim arr(.Cells.Count)
        If Not IsMissing(pairs) Then
            For i = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs) Step 2
                Set pairs(i) = pairs(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Offset(iIgnoreHeaderRows, 0)
            Next i
        End If

        For j = 1 To .Cells.Count
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(j).Text)) Or bIncludeBlanks Then
                If Not IsError(.Cells(j)) Or bIncludeErrors Then
                    If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(j).Text, arr, 0)) Or Not bUniqueList Then
                        If IsMissing(pairs) Then
                            arr(a) = .Cells(j).Text
                            a = a + 1
                        Else
                            For i = LBound(pairs) To UBound(pairs) Step 2
                                If Not CBool(Application.CountIfs(pairs(i).Cells(j), pairs(i + 1))) Then Exit For
                            Next i
                            If i > UBound(pairs) Then
                                arr(a) = .Cells(j).Text
                                a = a + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End With

    ReDim Preserve arr(a - 1)

    If bSorted Then
        Dim tmp As String
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
                If CBool(LCase(CStr(arr(i))) < LCase(CStr(arr(j))) And bDescending) Xor _
                   CBool(LCase(CStr(arr(i))) > LCase(CStr(arr(j))) And Not bDescending) Then
                    tmp = arr(j): arr(j) = arr(i): arr(i) = tmp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If

    TextJoinIfs = Join(arr, delim)
End Function
```

**[Syntax:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/dynamically-capture-a-number-of-cells-and-display-it-in-a-different-worksheet/50719050#50719050)**

```
=TextJoinIfs(<delimiter>, <options>, <header_rows>, <string_range>, [criteria_range1, criteria1], [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)
```

**[Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/dynamically-capture-a-number-of-cells-and-display-it-in-a-different-worksheet/50719050#50719050)**

[image]

**[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/dynamically-capture-a-number-of-cells-and-display-it-in-a-different-worksheet/50719050#50719050#example1)**

Simple TextJoin operation discarding blanks and errors, keeping only unique strings. Concatenated with a line feed (vbLF) delimiter but ignoring the first two header rows and sorted ascending.

```
=textjoinifs(CHAR(10), 24, 2, A:A)
```

[image]

**[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/dynamically-capture-a-number-of-cells-and-display-it-in-a-different-worksheet/50719050#50719050#example2)**

Expanded TextJoinIfs operation discarding blanks and errors, keeping only unique strings. Concatenated with a semi-colon/space delimiter. One condition set of range and criteria.

```
=textjoinifs("; ", 8, 0, B:B, A:A, A2)
```

[image]

**[Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/dynamically-capture-a-number-of-cells-and-display-it-in-a-different-worksheet/50719050#50719050#example2)**

Expanded TextJoinIfs operation discarding blanks and errors. Concatenated with a comma/space delimiter. Multiple condition pairs using maths comparisons.

```
=textjoinifs(", ", 0, 0, B:B, A:A, ">="&D2, A:A, "<="&E2)
```

[image]

---

<sub>Many thanks to the [Lorem Ipsum Generator](https://www.lipsum.com) for the sample string content.</sub>

Comment: You are brilliant mate!

Comment: is there a way to make the results show up alphabetically?

Comment: Yes, it works across worksheets. I've also added sorting and the ability to skip header row(s).

Comment: @Jeeped This is such a great answer - would you mind updating the verbiage to reflect Excel 2016 as well (assuming it's still functional for 2016, which I believe it is)?

Comment: @dwirony - Not clear on what *'reflect Excel 2016'* should entail. I do note that it adds *'expanded functionality for all versions'*.