# Substitute formula to add "&" with the last existing text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently using the following code :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^"))," ", ", "),"^"," ")
```

to achieve the result : text, text, text

However, I am struggling to change the code to get the result that if there's only 2 cells have data, it should be text & text. If 3 cells have data, it should be text, text & text.

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IFERROR(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^"))," ", ", "),"^"," "),MAX(IFERROR(FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^"))," ", ", "),"^"," "),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^"))," ", ", "),"^"," "))))),0)),1," &"),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^")&" "&SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^"))," ", ", "),"^"," "))`

Bit of a mouth full but this'll do it... This is an array formula, confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

[Source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2510-excel-find-first-last-number-in-string.html)

Comment: Thanks Glitch_Doctor for the solution! It works brilliant!

Comment: Hi @Glitch_Doctor I have another problem which I couldn't solve with your formula now. I need to combine 2 cells in each substitute, for example, i include second cell to C28&""&C30 which resulted in text(text). I wanted to have text (text) with a space in between. C28&""&C30 is working fine with all cells but when i make a space in between C28&" "&C30, all go haywire. For example : xxx (xxx) ,& xxx (xxx) or xxx (xxx) & xxx (xxx), xxx (xxx).

Comment: Hi @ChingLuTay, this is not how stack overflow works. As the scope has now changed a new question should be asked - I will take a look but could you post this as a new question linking this question or answer and I will respond in there?   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CONCATENATE in place of the &""&?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C28," ","^"))," ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C29," ","^"))," ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(C30," ","^")))," ",", "),"^"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xl2016/Office 365,

```
=textjoin(", ", true, c28:c30)
```

If you don't have the TEXTJOIN function, a good replacement UDF can be found at [TEXTJOIN for xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050).

Answer (score 0):

As a long-winded method that works across most versions of Excel, try this:

```
=IF(COUNTA(C28:C30)=3,TRIM(C28) & ", " & TRIM(C29) & ", " & TRIM(C29), IF(COUNTA(C28:C30)<2, TRIM(C28 & C29 & C30), IF(COUNTA(C28:C29)=2,TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29), IF(COUNTA(C29:C30)=2,TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29),TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29)))))
```

### How it works:

> `=IF(COUNTA(C28:C30)=3,TRIM(C28) & ", " & TRIM(C29) & ", " & TRIM(C29)`
>   If we have 3 items, join them together with `", "` between them

> `IF(COUNTA(C28:C30)<2, TRIM(C28 & C29 & C30)`
>   For 0 or 1 items, join everything together to show either nothing or the single item

> `IF(COUNTA(C28:C29)=2,TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29)`
>   If we have just the first and second items, join them together with `" & "` between items

> `IF(COUNTA(C29:C30)=2,TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29),TRIM(C28) & " & " & TRIM(C29))`
>   If we have just the second and third items, join them together with `" & "` in between
>   Otherwise, join the first and third items, with `" & "` in between

> `)))`
>   Close all of our `IF`s

### Simplified & more versatile Excel-365 *only* version:

```
=IF(COUNTA(C28:C30)=2, TEXTJOIN(" & ", true, c28:c30), TEXTJOIN(", ", true, c28:c30))
```

(If there are only 2 items, skip blanks and join them with `" & "`, otherwise skip blanks and join them with `", "`.  This also handles lists of any length, not just 3 items)