# If Statement for Visible Cells Only

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, visible, hidden-field

I am creating a form that autopopulates data when another form is pasted onto the workbook. I combined numbers from 5 different cells into one cell using this formula

```
=TEXT(L2,IF(L2=0," ","$000,000"))&"; "&TEXT(L3,IF(L3=0," ","$000,000"))&"; "&TEXT(L4,IF(L4=0," ","$000,000"))&"; "&TEXT(L5,IF(L5=0," ","$000,000"))&"; "&TEXT(L6,IF(L6=0," ","$000,000")).
```

Sometimes I will need to hide 3 rows, meaning I only need 2 of the numbers combined. The problem is that it still captures the 5 numbers. Is there a way to combine the visible cells only?

Comment: if you put an IF statement for each add on.  IF(ISBLANK(L3),"","; "&TEXT(L3,IF(L3=0," ","$000,000")).  Just repeat that check in each location that you know may come up blank.

Comment: in lieu of isblank you can also use L3=""

Comment: Are the cells hidden or just blank?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the blank cells use TEXTJOIN():

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,if(l2:l6<>"",TEXT(L2:L6,"$000,000"),""))
```

Use as an array formula, confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: [TEXTJOIN for xl2010/xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|83.5956#50719050)

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN("; ", TRUE, TEXT(L2:L6,"$000,000;;;"))` with CSE.