# How do I return multiple values from three cells into one cell in Excel? I need to return a value

Tags: excel, function

I have 3 cells in one worksheet and I want these cells to be returned into one cell in another sheet. If the value in a cell is an empty circle [Empty circle in first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXbc1.png) then "Dip not aligned" will be returned else "Dip aligned will be returned. Below is my logic for trying to return the 3 values in one cell, Excel gives me an error saying too many arguments.

```
=IF( Worksheet1!P8 = "○", "DP Not Aligned", "DP Aligned", IF( Worksheet1!Q8 
"○", "DITP Not Aligned", "DITP Aligned" ), IF( Worksheet1!R8 = "○", "DIIP 
Not Aligned", "DIIP Aligned" ))
```

Comment: Perhaps a TEXTJOINIFS user defined function like the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|83.6070#50719050).

Comment: What's the CODE or UNICODE for the `o` (or the filled bullet) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ampersand `&` to concatenate the results from your `IF()` statements, don't forget to use brackets to separate the `IF()` statements first.

Try this:

---

**Example values in spreadsheet:**

```
P8|Q8|R8
○ |○ |
```

**Formula:**

```
="DP " &(IF( Worksheet1!P8 = "○", "Not ", "")& "Aligned|" &"DITP "&( IF( Worksheet1!Q8 ="○", "Not ", "" ))&"Aligned|"&"DIIP "&( IF( Worksheet1!R8 = "○", "Not ", "" )))&"Aligned"
```

**Example output:**

```
DP Not Aligned|DITP Not Aligned|DIIP Aligned
```

---

*(*Edited for more condensed, clearer code suggested by @Jeeped in comments)*

**My original formula:**

```
=(IF( P8 = "○", "DP Not Aligned", "DP Aligned")& "|" &( IF( Q8 ="○", "DITP Not Aligned", "DITP Aligned" ))&"|"&( IF( R8 = "○", "DIIP Not Aligned", "DIIP Aligned" )))
```

Comment: Ooh, I agree it could be made a little more modular like that, I'll edit my answer - thanks!

Comment: @Jeeped Edited with both versions

Comment: Hmm. Not really an appreciable difference but still a very valid alternative.

Comment: @Jeeped not much difference in formula length, but a big difference in readability and reusability. If you're familiar with Python programming, I'd say your code is the more 'Pythonic' of the two.