# Un-merge a table to create unique values from two columns

Tags: excel

I have a table that has 2 columns:

'Project ID' and 'Tool size".

A Project can have more than one tool size. Currently in Excel every tool is entered in a new row with a duplicate project number.

I want to avoid Project Number duplicates and instead combine all tool sizes for that Project into one cell with a comma.

If a project contains 1 tool, leave as is.

If a project contains 2 tools, join the two tools in one cell for that project number.

If a project contains 3 tools, join the three tools in one cell for that project number and so on.

[image]

I tried `=IF($B2=B3,CONCATENATE(C2,",",C3),C2)`

But the formula won't work if there are more than two tools for a project

Comment: see [TEXTJOIN for xl2010/xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|83.2743#50719050)

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @Jeeped textjoin won't take care of the situation when there are more than two tools (B6=B7=B8). Concatenate should be enough, I just need to "Count the number of duplicate project numbers, and enter their respective tool size values in column D

Comment: @jeffreyweir 2013

Comment: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTFM.png) before you start discounting responses out of hand.

Comment: @Jeeped, thank you sir. You are right, but I was also missing the COUNTIF part, which I was more concerned about without realizing that concatenate won't work.

Comment: If you are OK with just one row per project in the desired result, you can use `Get&Transform`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's what I was thinkng with my question on Excel Version (as PQ is baked in to 2016, meaning you don't have to beg IT to install it). But I can't seem to nail the PQ query to do this. Would be keen to see someone use this approach..

Comment: @jeffreyweir I'll post something.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld. I do have PQ installed. I also had no idea how to use PQ for this task, I mostly use it for VLOOKUPS when I need to merge stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with one line per Project Number in your results, you can use `Get&Transform` for this.  Most steps can be done using the GUI.

> Group Rows by Project Number with an operation of "All Rows"
>
> Add Custom Column with a formula:

```
Table.ToList(
    Table.Transpose(
      Table.FromList(
        Table.Column([Tools],"Tool Size")
)
)
)
```

> In the above formula `Tools` is what I Named the new column when I grouped the rows and Tool Size is the name of the column in the original data
>
> Then you just `Expand` the new Tools column with a comma delimiter, and delete the table column.

The entire M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project Number", Int64.Type}, {"Tool Size", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Project Number"}, {{"Tools", each _, type table}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.ToList(
    Table.Transpose(
      Table.FromList(
        Table.Column([Tools],"Tool Size")
)
)
)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Tools"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the lesson, Ron.+1

Comment: @jeffreyweir thank you! I do have PQ. I just didn't know PQ is capable of this, learn something every day

Comment: @Victor-------- It's the formula in the custom column that required research for me who has minimal familiarity with M code.