# Best way to handle optional parameters in UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, optional-parameters

I have a function similar to this

```
Public Function func(ByRef mandatory_arg1 As Range, ByRef mandatory_arg2 As Range, _
                     Optional ByRef optional_Arg1 As Range, Optional ByRef optional_arg2 As Range, _
                     Optional ByRef optional_arg3 As Range, Optional ByRef optional_arg4 As Range, _
                     Optional ByRef optional_arg5 As Range, Optional ByRef optional_arg6 As Range) As Double
    func = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(mandatory_arg1, ...) / WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(mandatory_arg2, ...)
End Function
```

What is the best way to handle the cases where arguments are missing? Is using an If-Else structure similar to

```
if IsMissing(optional_Arg1) or IsMissing(optional_Arg2) Then
    ' ...
EndIf
```

the only way? Or will `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(...)` ignore arguments of `Nothing`?

Comment: You can use IsMissing only with Variant, not with Range, but you can use and check for default values.

Comment: You should look at Paramarray http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml

Comment: Very hard to tell without knowing what your real function's purpose, and likely opinion-based on this site. However, if you can share the real code, [codereview.se] can probably help.

Comment: You might be interested in how I handled optional range/criteria pairs in a [TEXTJOINIFS UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|86.6482#50719050).

Answer (score 1):

Use a ParamArray and cycle through the ranges passed across.

```
Public Function func(ByRef mandatory_arg1 As Range, ByRef mandatory_arg2 As Range, _
                     ParamArray rngs()) As Double
    dim i as long

    If IsMissing(rngs) Then
        'no optional ranges
    End If


    For i = LBound(rngs) To UBound(rngs)
        'process rngs(i)
    Next i

end function
```

Comment: That works for most cases where the UDF does its own thing, but falls apart when the optional parameters are then passed as optional arguments to another function, as seems to be the case for the OP. IMO that question would be a better fit on [codereview.se]... **if** it included the real, actual, complete code.