# Excel Concatenate with IFS and AND/OR

Tags: excel

I need to concatenate Descriptions in Column G, but only those description where Column D(SearchType) = 7.

The Concatenated Description must also just reflect on the last line before the DocumentNumber (Column B) resets and only include those Searchtype 7 descriptions of the same DocumentNumber.

I've tried multiple `AND` , `OR`. `IF`, `IFS` and `CONCATENATE` variations, but don't seem to get it right. Such as

```
=+IF(AND(F4=0,F3<>0,F2<>0,F1<>0),CONCATENATE(G4,G3),FALSE)
```

but I cannot figure out how to "Reset" the formula

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post an example of the desired output? Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [this may be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|86.6923#50719050)