# Concatenate all data by rows and remove numbers

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need help writing a code for excel that takes all active data in a row and concatenates it into one cell and then have this loop through all active rows.

The problem I am running into is that the amount of columns and rows is completely random so I just need it to take into account all existing data.

Lastly, I want the concatenation to only include letters, so no numbers or "," or anything else.

Please help if you are able.

Here is a before and after images, if that helps.

*Before*

[image: Before]

*After*

[image: After]

Comment: There are several 'text only' regex-based UDFs on this site. Wrap one of those around TextJoin or [some other concatenation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|86.7068#50719050).

Comment: What is the rule that has you also remove the `comma` from the second row concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might work - that macro avaoids every special character and numbers. Copy and Paste that code into a new module in your VBA editor and run the sub "CreateString".

```
Sub CreateString()
    Dim LastRow%: LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim strConcatenate$, i%, j%
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    ws.Range("A:A").Clear
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 2 To LastColumn(i) 'Calls function "LastColumn" to get the last column of each row
            strConcatenate = strConcatenate & FindReplace(ws.Cells(i, j))
        Next j
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = strConcatenate 'This will past the finished string into column [A] in the specific row
        strConcatenate = "" 'blanks the string, so the next string in the next row is fresh
    Next i
End Sub

Function LastColumn(row%) As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    LastColumn = ws.Cells(row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function

Function FindReplace(CellValue$)
    Dim strPattern$: strPattern = "[^A-Za-z]+"    'Pattern to only take care of letters
    Dim strReplace$: strReplace = ""    'Replace everything else with blank
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    FindReplace = regex.Replace(CellValue, strReplace) 'RegEx Function replaces the pattern with blank
End Function
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: You are a genius, this is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @Valborg, glad I could help.