# Using Countif, Small, and Search to reconcile data sets

Tags: excel, database, vba, user-defined-functions, countif

I have this vague idea that I should be able to use the above formulas to compile a list of combined values. There may be a much easier way to do this but my brain has started down this track so I thought it best to float it out there and see what it is that I get back.

I've made an example wherein I have 4 donut shops, they each have more than one location and I would like to perform two functions: One would (using the small function and the countif value) go through and return each value in a new cell in the same row, Second would be using the countif and small functions to concatenate each value into a orderly string.

My thought with this is I will then be able to use conditional formatting on each of the individual listings in a Search function (or index match) to tell me which names from database one (as associated with Company A) lineup with names as listed in database two (as associated with Company A). I know I'm referencing an example set and the corresponding application to an actual data set.

```
                                              Count   Towns
Dunkin Donuts   Norwell          Dunkin Donuts  6   
Honey Dew       Hanover          Honey Dew      3   
Dunkin Donuts   Springfield      Beard Papa     2   
Cronut          Walnut Creek     Cronut         2   
Beard Papa      Culver City         
Cronut          Santa Monica            
Dunkin Donuts   Summerville         
Honey Dew       Charlestown         
Beard Papa      Oakland         
Dunkin Donuts   Dorchester          
Dunkin Donuts   Jamaica Plain           
Dunkin Donuts   San Francisco           
Honey Dew       Agoura
```

Comment: You need an array formula with TEXTJOIN or a [vba udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|85.3071#50719050).

Comment: Is there a reason a pivot table won't work?

Comment: OK great thanks @Jeeped that helps a lot with one part of the puzzle. My though with the next bit, is that the countif will tell the function how many ID values to go through, creating a cell and filling it with the associated contact name from the primary data set. From there it shouldn't be too difficult to structure the whole array with conditional formatting (green for exact match, yellow for partial, red for no match).