# If column contains Y concatenate headings

Tags: excel

Got a list of data with 7 columns each with a Y in, I want to add a formula that will check for a Y in the column then concatenate the headings if correct and ignore if not.

See below example

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using office 2016 , you can use TEXTJOIN to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get the TextJoinIfs to work, sadly, looks neat. If you have the same problem maybe this can be a solution. Not pretty I know...

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",A2),FALSE),"col 1",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",B2),FALSE),"col 2",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",C2),FALSE),"col 3",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",D2),FALSE),"col 4",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",E2),FALSE),"col 5",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",F2),FALSE),"col 6",""),IF(IFERROR(MATCH("Y",G2),FALSE),"col 7",""),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [this User Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050#50719050).

```
=TextJoinIfs(", ", 0, 0, B$1:H$1, B2:H2, "y")
```

[image]