# Logic function to combine all matching text into one cell

Tags: excel

I am looking for help with a formula that looks for all matching text and combines the results into a single cell. For example if the Country is Colombia I want a single cell to list all of the names that match Colombia.

```
    ColA        ColB
A1: COUNTRY     NAME
A2: Argentina   John Doe
A3: Bahamas     Jan Doe
A4: Colombia    James Doe
A5: Colombia    Jason Doe
A6: Colombia    Julian Doe
```

I've toyed around with CONCANTENATE and MATCH however they don't seem to be getting me what I need.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TEXTJOIN for xl2010/xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|83.3296#50719050)

Comment: Great outcome! Thanks!