# Vba Concatenate multiple columns until blank

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a macro to concatenate multiple columns until find an empty cell, when it finds should put the concatenated text in the first cell. [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s5m8.png) shows how it should work. In this example I have values from B to M but it can varies. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Will the number of columns be different in different rows as well? Also, will column B a good guess to get a last row value ?

Comment: If you have a version of Excel that has `TEXTJOIN`, you can use that. Otherwise you can use a UDF version - an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, see comments for more details:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub concatenateValues()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name") '
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row at column B
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, Column.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last column at row 1, assuming you have at least headers

Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) 'declare and allocate your data to an array

Dim R As Long, C As Long

For R = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData) 'for each row in your data, start at row 2
    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2) 'for each column in your data, start at column 2
        arrData(R, 1) = arrData(R, 1) & arrData(R, C) 'concatenate the values
    Next C
Next R

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) = arrData 'put the values back into the sheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution. I assumed that the second column would always have a value in it.

```
Sub Concat()
Dim i As Integer, Sht As Worksheet, Str As String
i = 3
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Change this to whatever sheet you're using
Str = Sht.Cells(1, 2).Value
Do Until Sht.Cells(1, i).Value = ""
    Str = Str & "-" & Sht.Cells(1, i).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop
Sht.Cells(1, 1).Value = Str
End Sub
```